# Can I deploy custom data feed?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, data-feeds

I have next situation: I want to deploy my token and for others SCs I need to use Chainlink data feed to get price of the token.
But, as token is new, that's why Chainlink doens't have supported data feed. So how I can get/create such data feed and is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price data of a token in Chainlink's data feed is provided by multiple decentralized oracle nodes within the Chainlink [DON(Decentralized Oracle Network)](https://docs.chain.link/architecture-overview/architecture-decentralized-model?parent=gettingStarted#decentralized-oracle-network).

Therefore, before deploying any data feed contract, it is necessary to have a number of oracle nodes willing to provide price data for your token. The aggregated reports are then sent to the data feed contract through [OCR (Off-chain reporting)](https://docs.chain.link/architecture-overview/off-chain-reporting?parent=gettingStarted).

Even if you can deploy a data feed contract yourself, the contract will not contain the price data of your token.

If you are interested in adding a new data feed, please [contact Chainlink Official](https://chain.link/contact).

Comment: After my own research I have I came to the same conclusion. In addition I can say that chainlink has additional requirements for tokens to support. For example minimum amount of liquidity and amount of supported exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

You can still get the price but it depends on the DEX you're going to use:

- Uniswap V2: you can get a "time weighted average price" TWAP, but you need to deploy your own contract, follow the [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/concepts/core-concepts/oracles) or this [guide](https://soliditydeveloper.com/uniswap-oracle).
- Uniswap V3: it's easier to use, check the [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/concepts/protocol/oracle) or [guide](https://tienshaoku.medium.com/a-guide-on-uniswap-v3-twap-oracle-2aa74a4a97c5).
- Other: check their docs or ask the developers, most likely they have something similar as Uniswap.

Remember that these prices can still be manipulated if the liquidity is low. They are however the best alternative to Chainlink you can get. I don't think they'll list your token until it's listed on a CEX anyway.